# Dash Plotly Graph height/width aspect ratio

Tags: graph, aspect-ratio, plotly-dash

I'm using a `dcc.Graph` in my Dash app where `figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=go.Layout())`

I've been playing with `go.Layout`'s size and aspect ratio settings for almost two hours now, and I can't seem to figure out how to continue allowing my plot to scale with window size (so not using `height`/`width` arguments), but to set the height/width aspect ratio to 1.5. Is this possible?

In 2017 it seems that it [required resorting to CSS](https://community.plot.ly/t/height-aspect-ratio/6711), but I'm hoping things have changed by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible within the figure spec, no. You’ll have to use a responsive figure and enforce the aspect ratio in CSS (although this isn’t particularly easy in CSS either unfortunately)